# Android: ASyncTask's behavior contrary to documentation

Tags: recursion, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

First time writing an `AsyncTask` and I seem to have a subtle design flaw that prevents both `ProgressDialog`, `ProgressBar`, and even `Log.d()` from working properly. I suspect that somehow I am not actually creating a new thread/task.

## Short: the symptoms

- A `ProgressDialog` is created in the constructor, and the code orders Android to show it in `onPreExecute()`, but the dialog never shows.
- `onProgressUpdate()` is supposed to execute whenever I call `publishProgress()` from within `doInBackground()`, correct? Well, it doesn't. Instead, it executes when `doInBackground()` completes.

## Long: investigations

Things I have verified through the emulator and, when possible, on a phone:

- `onPreExecute()` is definitely called

  - the progress bar is not reset until after `doInBackground()` completes
  - `update_dialog.show()` is definitely executed, but the dialog does not appear unless I remove the `.dismiss()` in `onPostExecute()`; I imagine dialog is, like the progress bar, not shown until after `doInBackground()` completes, but is naturally immediately dismissed
  - the code will happily show dialogs when no computation is involved
- `doInBackground()` definitely invokes `publishProgress()`

  - when it does, `onProgressUpdate()` does not execute immediately! that is, I have a breakpoint in the function, and the debugger does not stop there until after `doInBackground()` completes! (perhaps this is a phenomenon of the debugger, rather than `doInBackground()`, but I observe the same symptoms on a mobile device)
  - the progress bar gets updated... only after `doInBackground()` completes everything
  - similarly, the `Log.d()` data shows up in Android Monitor only after `doInBackground()` completes everything
- and of course the dialog does not show up either in the emulator or on a device (unless I remove `.dismiss()` from `onPostExecute()`)

Can anyone help find the problem? Ideally I'd like a working dialog, but as Android has deprecated that anyway I'd be fine with a working progress bar.

## Code

Here are the essentials, less the details of computation &c.:

Where I call the `AsyncTask` from the main thread:

```
if (searching) { // this block does get executed!
   Compute_Task my_task = new Compute_Task(overall_context, count);
   my_task.execute(field, count, max_x, max_y);
   try { result = my_task.get(); } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

The `AsyncTask` itself:

```
private class Compute_Task extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Integer> {

   public Compute_Task(Context context, int count) {
      super();
      current_positions = 0;
      update_dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
      update_dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
      update_dialog.setCancelable(false);
      update_dialog.setTitle("Thinking");
      update_dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
   }

   protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      update_dialog.show();
      ProgressBar pb = ((ProgressBar) ((Activity) overall_context).findViewById(R.id.progress_bar));
      pb.setMax(base_count);
      pb.setProgress(0);
   }

   protected void onPostExecute() {
      super.onPostExecute();
      update_dialog.dismiss();
   }

   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
      super.onProgressUpdate(values);
      ProgressBar pb = ((ProgressBar) ((Activity) overall_context).findViewById(R.id.progress_bar));
      pb.setMax(base_count);
      pb.incrementProgressBy(1);
      Log.d(tag, values[0].toString());
   }

   protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params) {
      Integer result = compute_scores(
         (boolean[][]) params[0], (Integer) params[1], (Integer) params[2], (Integer) params[3], 0)
      );
      return result;
   }

   public int compute_scores(boolean[][] field, int count, int max_x, int max_y, int level) {
      int result, completed = 0;
      switch(count) {
         // LOTS of computation goes on here,
         // including a recursive call where all params are modified
         if (level == 0)
            publishProgress(++completed);
      }
   }

   ProgressDialog update_dialog;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is basically the same issue as the one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583137/asynctask-block-ui-thread-and-show-progressbar-with-delay?noredirect=1&lq=1). The "fatal" line is this one:

```
try { result = my_task.get(); } catch (Exception e) { }
```

Apparently this puts the UI thread into deep sleep. **One should not use `get()` with an `AsyncTask` unless one is willing to suspend the UI thread.** We have to perform a little magic in `onPostExecute()` instead.

Although it turns out that this was a duplicate, I didn't find it until after I wrote it, because I didn't realize the thread was blocking.